# Executing a script

Tags: php

I need to execute a script within php, i tried almost everything..

```
http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?username=user&password=******&sendername=Vfup&mobileno= '.$f.' &message='.$message1.''
```

I tried java script, but i $f and $message1 are variables, so i cant use **echo** twice

Is there any function in php, which automatically opens the above link in a new window and i need the remaining part of the php code to execute normally without being affected. Will provide more details if required..

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

PHP executes on the server, so is not capable of opening windows.  If you want this to happen on the client side you will have to echo it out as JavaScript that the browser can execute.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to get this alternate process to fire, then you might want to just call `file_get_contents` from your current script:

```
file_get_contents('http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?'.
                  'username=user&password=******&sendername=Vfup&mobileno= '.$f.
                  '&message='.$message1.'');
```

When file_get_contents is given a URL, it will load all of the data from that URL into a local string. This means, in this case, that the server will do what you are trying to get the browser to do for you.

If that is not sufficient, then you will need to use the js function `window.open` and pass it that URL:

```
 <script>window.open("<?php echo $url; ?>");</script>
```

Comment: +1 That's twice today you've turned up and given a better answer :)